# Repeated measures with small sample size

Tags: regression

In repeated measures longitudinal studies, you only have few measurements for each subject

We fit longitudinal regression to this data and estimate regression coefficients for the different subjects and variance of these (ex: individual level, random effects)

But I am still confused about this.

We are estimating coefficients with little information. EX: if I only had 6 data points in general (e.g. height of 6 people) - any person would tell you that you can not calculate the average height and the variance of the average height for only these 6 people because the sample size is too small.

But in longitudinal regression , it looks like the same thing is happening - we are estimating coefficients  using few observations for each subject. Dont we need larger samples for reliable estimation?

I thought that maybe to fix this problem, we can say that the average response variable in each cluster (ex: you have students and you know the state-city-school-classroom ... each classroom is a cluster) is now a random effect. Now, we dont model individual students, all students in same cluster are considered as identical. So the individual effect (ex: random effect) is for the average of each cluster, not on each student.

Is this a quick hack to fix the problem of regression coeffecient/variance of regression coeffecient estimation for longitudinal models? Is it logical?

Comment: Can you clarify what is your regression model? What is your dependent variable and what is your independent variable? Is time the independent? Or some other variable measured at each time point?

Comment: hi, its a longitudinal regression

Comment: Yes, I know. I was asking what is your predictor variable and what is your dependent variable, and how are you modeling them (e.g. as continuous or categorical). "Longitudinal regression" can refer to different things.