# Is it safer to model groups of people instead of individuals?

Tags: regression, repeated-measures

I posted this question before and am still confused:

If you take a person and ask him to hold his breath and measure how long he can hold his breath. Then you make him do this 2 more times (3 times in total). 3 measurements is probably too small to calculate the mean and variance for how long he can hold his breath (ex: maybe he started coughing one of those times which made him hold his breath for a very short period of time that is not representative of his real average). There is defintely not enough data to calculate the variance.

In repeated measurement studies, you usually only have 3-4 measurements per patient.

In longitudinal regression models, you estimate beta coeffecients and the variance of the beta coeffecients for individuals in the repeated measures study. Is this really a good idea because you have so little data for each individual?

For example, if you have 100 people with a disease: 50 of them take a medicine and 50 of them dont. We want to see if the white blood cell count of the people who take medicine is better over time compared to those who dont (ex: measurements are taken 3 times over 1 year for all people ... we measure gender, weight as predictors and the response is white blood cell count).

Would it be safer to make a longitudinal regression model that models the white blood cell count of the average diseased person on medicine and the white blood cell count of the average diseased person not on medicine? This way there is more data to use for mean/variance calculations. The model is safer (ex: better sample size) but less specific (ex: for a group of people instead of individual persons).

Therefore, is it safer to make a more vague/general longitudinal regression model that only models the average behavior of group instead of the behavior of individual .... due to problems from small sample sizes of individuals encountered in repeated measure studies? The smallest unit of measure is the group and not the individual now.

Comment: What is the original question that you posted before? Can you share the link?

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that this is very either/or, but often we do both? A mixed model is hierarchical with a conditional part for specific subjects (with some shrinkage going on, you still use more than just that subject to estimate its random effect[s]) and a marginal part that applies to the population. Which part you'd use depends on the goal: are you a physician wanting to make a decision for *this specific patient* or are you a payer that wants to know if the drug will work *for the population*? Note, some models (e.g. GEE) might do repeated measures but are only marginal.

Comment: original question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/628006/repeated-measures-with-small-sample-size

Comment: pbulls... thx for your clarifications. in general, is marginal model less riskier because its describing average population behavior .... compared to conditional model that is describing individuals? this is because marginal models are using more data for the estimation?

Comment: we also posted follow up q: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/629142/why-does-gee-only-work-for-marginal-models

Comment: Under the original question you were asked to specify *precisely* the regression model you are talking about. You didn't do it, but it would really help a lot to see how exactly you model "the beta coefficient for an individual". If it's a standard random effect, note that there is only *one* parameter for all individuals, namely the random effect variance. The individual "beta"-values are predictions not parameters, so you shouldn't think of these as requiring many additional observations (basically this is taken care of by the restrictive assumptions behind random effects).